# Android display images in ListView from its path

Tags: android, listview

In android I am trying to display images based on their path in ListView using Simple Adapter. So, I have images paths stored in form of string in my database table. Now I want to display them in ListView. How to do it?

Comment: So what is the issue ? You can decode it and get bitmap as a result.

Comment: using a library like Glide would be better option.

Comment: It is not good question to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write..

```
String photoUrl="your image url;
    try{

        if(photoUrl !=null) {
            yourImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(photoUrl));
        }

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy if you are using Glide/Picasso library for image loading. You just need to pass file path and rest process glide will do itself.

e.g.

```
Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.place_holder)
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(imageView);
```

But make sure your file path is not empty and is file, otherwise you might caught an exception.

Comment: I actually made some modification to the question asked.. Have a look at the updated one.. and suggest me on how to go about it.

Comment: get data from cursor adapter and find the image path and pass it to the glide, it will load your image

Comment: Thanks.. I able to get the images in ListView with a different approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, it reads file in two steps

1. Read file to get width and height
2. Adjust scaling and load

You can adjust scaling in second step (see comment) to match your imageview. If you don't need scaling, you can just do it in one step (ignore first step then).

```
//Read file
Options options = new Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inDither = false;  // for older API level
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);

if(options.outWidth <= 0 || options.outHeight <= 0) {
    return null;
}

// scale and load
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inDither = false;  
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
options.inSampleSize = 1;  //Adjust scaling

Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
```